# Rails 4 - Rendering partials instead of views in controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is the show action from my UsersController, which I'm using for the profile view of each user on my site:

```
def show

    user = User.find(params[:id])

    @conversations ||= user.mailbox.inbox.all

    @active_requests = user.requests.all.select { |r| r.request_complete == nil }
    @completed_requests = user.requests.all.select { |r| r.request_complete != nil }

    @reviews_received = Review.received_by_user(user)
    @reviews_given = Review.given_by_user(user)

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html 
        format.json
    end

end
```

As you can see, I'm accessing four different models within this one action. I'd like to move these instance variable declarations into each model's respective controller, in custom actions. 
I'll need to attach a partial to each of those actions somehow, which I will then render inside the `users/show.erb` view.

I'm not sure how to render a partial and have that partial 'attached' to an action, so that it has access to that action's instance variables. Here's what I've done 
so far for the Review model:

I created an action, `index_reviews_received`, inside `ReviewsController`, and this partial: `reviews/_index_reviews_received.erb`.

Inside `users/show.erb`, I tried 
     `<%= render 'reviews/index_reviews_received' %>`, but could not access the `@reviews_received`  instance variable within the `index_reviews_received` action in `ReviewsController`.

**reviews/_index_reviews_received.erb**

```
<% @reviews_received.each do |received| %>

   <%= received.feedback %>
   <%= received.rating  %>
   ...

<% end %>
```

**ReviewsController**

```
def index_reviews_received

#not actual query, just keeping it simple while I figure this out.
    @reviews_received = Review.all.limit(10)

end
```

**routes for Review**

```
resources :reviews do
      collection do
          get :index_reviews_received
          get :index_reviews_given    
      end
end
```

If you think I'm going about this the wrong way, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems you are trying to render reviews/_index_reviews_received.erb inside of users/show.erb. While you can do this, you will not get the instance variable from ReviewsController because you are never instantiating the ReviewsController and calling the appropriate action. When you navigate to localhost:3000/users/123, you are (hopefully) routing to the show action in the UsersController, and that's it. Only when you navigate to localhost:3000/reviews/index_reviews_received will you instantiate ReviewsController and call the action, which creates the instance var.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@stefvhuynh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1981385/stefvhuynh) is correct. You have instantiated the UsersController#show method and only get the instance variables that are called within it.

Anything that you need (instance variables) when you show a user should be found within that call. You can still use partials to DRY up your view.

Comment: Thanks, I understand. I guess what I should be asking is 'how can I reduce the size of my action?'. Is it not a bad practice to have so many instance variables? Would you say it matters, or is it just necessary when I need access to those models?

Comment: If it is what you need to render your view, then use what you need. When you need access, you need access. In the future, when you know how your application is used, you can refactor to more fit your users.